# 403 Error using WideImage with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-permissions, filepath, http-status-code-403

My application uses WideImage successfully to crop & resize images. I call this on images using the following:

```
<img src="<?=asset_url()?>scripts/thumb.php?src=<?=$post['picture']?>" />
```

Where `asset_url()` is a function that returns the path to my assets folder. The folder structure is:

```
| assets
| application
| system
```

This works fine, but my assets folder should just contain images, JS files and CSS.

If I try and move the `thumb.php` file to any folder within the `application` directory, I get a **403 error**.

**Is this a feature of CodeIgniter to stop direct access to files? If so, how do I get around it?**

I'm using a default `.htaccess` file, which looks something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>  
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the 403 by your webserver or by codeigniter?

Comment: How can I tell? Looks like a standard webserver 403 to me.

Comment: What is the request URI that gives you the 403? Maybe it's for a directory and directory listing is denied by apache?

Comment: The URI is `thumb.php` which and the file is in the normal Views folder.

Comment: It's not a view, so don't place it into the views folder. It does not belong there. How can you assume it's working there?

Comment: I don't assume anything - I'm asking! I had it working outside of the entire CodeIgniter directory, but once it is placed inside, it stops working.

Comment: Please don't feel offended, it was not meant so. Just wanted to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a correct behaviour of any framework. It's just dont' give you the freedom to make your app completely non-understandable by any other developers.

For example if I developer of X-framework and don't expect blah.php in the app folder -- the good framework will help ME (not the author :) ). So in the result we will have a good quality code.

But in your concrete question, I think you should just create some controller/action -- and not directly call blah.php

Comment: I figured that was the case - I knew there was a 'proper' way to be doing what I was trying to achieve. Of course, when you have something that is working, it's hard to commit to starting again just to make it 'right'. Ho hum.

Comment: @Joe, you should always struggle with this feeling about working vs proper. It's better to do proper, as after some time it becomes obvious, that working isnt' so supportive as proper.